# Conditionally update row based on other update result

Tags: mysql, sql-update

In my `Mysql` database, I have a table of data like below

```
id  | id_fk  | name   | address  | city  | priority | status |
--------------------------------------------------------------
1   | 1      | name1  | address1 | city1 |          | active |
2   | 2      | name2  | address2 | city2 | primary  | active |
3   | 1      | name3  | address3 | city3 | primary  | active |
4   | 1      | name4  | address4 | city4 |          | active |
5   | 1      | name5  | address5 | city5 |          | active |
6   | 3      | name6  | address6 | city6 | primary  | active |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here, `id` is row id, `id_fk` is reference from another table. `status` is data status. If the data deleted, then it will be `deleted`. and `priority` is for refer the default address.

My problem is,

**If I delete the address with `id = 3` then the there will not be any first priority address for 'id_fk = 1'. I would like to change the status of 'id=3' as `deleted` and set `priority` of any one of the other address with 'id_fk = 1' as `primary`.**

Simple `UPDATE` query will not do this. Is there any way to do that? Thank in advance.

Comment: I've tried doing that using a case-when statement and an if statement but failed :( 
For now the best answer I can give you is to just do it using 2 update queries (if the first one changed a row, update another row to status `primary`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do this with two `UPDATE` queries:

```
UPDATE myTable SET status = 'deleted' WHERE id = 3
;
UPDATE myTable as a, 
(SELECT id_fk, max(id) 
  FROM myTable 
    WHERE id_fk = 1 
    AND status NOT IN ('deleted') 
  GROUP BY id_fk
) as b
SET a.priority = 'primary' 
WHERE a.id_fk = 1 
AND a.id = b.id
```

Comment: You've confused priority and status a couple of times. should be `SET status = 'deleted'` and
`AND status NOT IN ('deleted') ` (or `AND status != 'deleted'`).
Other than that I think this should be the answer;